# Deleting all shapes on a PowerPoint slide

Tags: vb.net, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to delete all slides on a PowerPoint shape with VBA. What i'm trying to do is simply:

```
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
       sh.Delete
    Next 
Next
```

But this does not delete all shapes as illustrated in the image below: (The grey arrow is a shape i'm adding before running the code below, but doesn't dissapear either)

Any idea on what i'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Seem ok to me, under what event are you adding the shapes to begin with?

Comment: The shapes you see on the left slide is added manually. Before the above code is executed i added two arrow-lines to the slide from the code to see how it would behave. The grey line-arrow on the right slide is one of these arrows. The problem is present both if i add shapes from within the code or add them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That truly is interesting and I was able to re-create the problem.  I also first tried to take a count and iterate through the count; however, the problem is that how many shapes are on there refreshes real-time.  What I mean is if it counted the shapes at one point in time as 2 shapes, then when a shape is deleted there are only 1 shape on there.  Therefore your best bet is to loop through the count of shapes deleting the first shape each time as such.

```
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    TotalShapes = sld.Shapes.Count

    For i = TotalShapes to 1 step -1 

        sld.Shapes(i).Delete

    Next

Next
```

Thanks,
Sean W.

Comment: Well i'm glad you could re-produce the error. Nice spotted. Is it correct understood that after the sh.Delete call, the whole slide is updated (and re-rendered to the screen), and when the for each loop tries to iterate the second time, the shape which was at the second index is now shifted to the first index and the shape is thereby not deleted? Seems quite inefficient in my opinion

Comment: Yep it seems like your understanding is correct.  That is certainly pretty strange.

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether the slide is re-rendered;  the same thing will happen if the presentation is opened windowlessly (ie, nothing is shown on screen at all). It's more that in a For/Each loop, there's an implicit counter.  You're essentially doing For x = 1 to Whatever.Count.  On the first iteration of the loop, you delete Whatever(1).  On the second iteration, you delete Whatever(2) but because you already deleted Whatever(1), what was Whatever(2) is now Whatever(1), so deleting Whatever(2) deletes what was previously Whatever(3), leaving the new Whatever(1), was Whatever(2)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just say:

```
sld.Shapes.Range.Delete
```

Comment: Do you have to define osld? If i run the code i get an "Object required" error (although i would think that the code should select all shapes when selecting Range?)

Comment: Use your sld rather than osld in John's example.

Answer (score 1):

```
typo: missing 0 in > 0

While ActivePresentation.Slides.Count > 0
      While ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count **> 0**
            ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Delete
      Wend
      ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Delete
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For x = sld.shapes.count to 1 step -1
       sld.shapes(x).Delete
    Next 
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the easiest way is:

```
while ActivePresentation.Slides.count>0
  while ActivePresentation.Slides(1).shapes.count>
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).shapes(1).delete
  wend
  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).delete
wend
```